# Strange characters in console of Ubuntu Vagrant box

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant

I provisioned the Vagrant box Laravel Homestead. It is running Ubuntu 14.04.

When I see output from Node.js, I get strange characters such as `Â»` when I would expect `>>` or I get `€â”` when expecting a `-` and so on.

What might cause this in the configuration of the OS or Vagrant box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this happens only on Windows, which can't seem to display the characters correctly in the console.

Only solution I could find was switching to a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I had such a problem as well when accessing my Vagrant box via PuTTY.
In my case, the solution was simply to change the character set setting to UTF-8:

Change settings → Window → Translation → Received data assumed to be in which character set → `UTF-8`. Be sure to apply this change to the saved PuTTY session as well.